# Ring Extension and Projective Resolution

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

For $R$ commutative ring and $N,M$ two $R$-modules, I have the following diagram 
    [image]

where $(P_i,\partial_i)$ are projective modules of the projective resolution of M, $f$ is an $R$-module homomorphism and
\begin{align*}
&V:=\{(f(z),-\partial_1(z)):z\in P_1\}\\
&i(x):=[x,0] \qquad \qquad p([x,y]):=\partial_0(y)
\end{align*}
I want to prove that if $f\circ \partial_2=0$, then the sequence below is exact.

I have some trouble proving that $ \operatorname{Ker}(p)\subset  \operatorname{Im}(i)$. In particular, for $[x,y]\in  \operatorname{Ker}(p)$ , then $y\in \operatorname{Ker}(\partial_0)= \operatorname{Im}(\partial_1)$. Hence, there exists $z\in P_1$ such that $\partial_1(z)=y$. I want to prove that, there exists $t\in N$ such that $(x-t)=f(z)$. This is true only if $x\in  \operatorname{Im}(f)$....Why $x\in  \operatorname{Im}(f)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $p$ is well defined. Indeed, if $(x,y)\in V$, then $x=f(z)$ and $y=-\partial_1(z)$, so
$$
\partial_0(y)=-\partial_0\partial_1(z)=0
$$
Let $[x,y]\in\ker p$, which means $\partial_0(y)=0$. The top row is exact by assumption, so $y=\partial_1(z)$.

What you want to show is that there is $x'$ such that
$$
i(x')=[x',0]=[x,y]
$$
that means $(x-x',y)\in V$. Thus you need $z'$ with
$$
x-x'=f(z'),\quad y=-\partial_1(z')
$$
An obvious candidate for $z'$ is $z'=-z$. Choose $x'=x+f(z)$ and you're done.

Comment: Another question: are there any properties of $P_0$ that ensure the existence of an homomorphism $q:(N\oplus P_0)/V\to P_0$ such that $\partial_0\circ q=p$?

Comment: @Jackristin $P_0$ is projective…

Comment: Okay but given $q: P_0\to (N\oplus P_0)/V$ from the definition of projective module, I need a retraction for $q$. It exists?